# How to validate image volume size which is sent to Rails server through API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl

I would like to validate image volume size when a JSON data is sent to Rails server through API.

Image binary data is sent as string parameter:

```
curl -v -X POST "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"icon":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4..."}'
```

I want the server to return a error message telling that user should send a image less than 10 MB but not 500 error.
How could I solve this?

Comment: what do you use for image upload?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model which has an image attribute, I'd recommend using the Paperclip gem which works like a charm. You can have model validations like this:

```
has_attached_file :photo
validates_attachment :photo, :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }, :size => { in: 0..10.megabytes }
```